# Applying MahApps.Metro Dark theme

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

I am relatively new to WPF and I am trying to apply Windows Metro Dark theme to my entire application.

I used the following in my Apps.xaml and I can see the Windows Metro Light theme properly.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Now I want to change the theme to Dark. I understand I can always use,

> ThemeManager.ChangeTheme()

But I believe there should be a way to do this with XAML effective to all the windows of the application.

**My Question :**  Can someone point me how to do this without using ThemeManager in source code?

Comment: You can create baehavior to achieve that. Refer to this - http://svetoslavsavov.blogspot.in/2009/07/switching-wpf-interface-themes-at.html

Comment: @RohitVats : How do I find the available options and paths? Through object explorer?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try to use `BaseDark` instead of `BaseLight`. Try to change this line :

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
```

to this :

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseDark.xaml" />
```

That did the trick for me. Screenshot of my application using MahApps BaseDark and BaseLight accents:

**BaseDark**
[image]
**BaseLight**
[image]

Comment: Great.Thank you very much. This was the one I was thinking of? But one more question. How do I get the available list of Accents? :-)

Comment: well, I suspect accents is part that hasn't been documented yet (can't find documentation about it anywhere). But you can get accent list by peeking the source [here](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/tree/master/MahApps.Metro/Styles/Accents)

Comment: And one interesting observation. I create a new window from the parent window. new childWindow().show(). The theme has been applied but I can see that the title bar is not in Metro style. All the controllers are in Metro. I am investigating this. Any clue?

Comment: Found the mistake. A silly one. I've forgotten to add Controls:MetroWindow tag. Accepting the answer.